# Java program Opencv unsatisfiedlinkerror

Tags: java, c++, linux, eclipse, opencv

I have a java application designed to run in the Linux environment, developed using Opencv and **Eclipse - Ubuntu 14.04**. It runs fine inside Eclipse and produces a .jar on export. The program .jar works perfectly on the system where the opencv is installed.

```
java -Dpath.java.library="/home/me/opencv/build/lib" -jar program.jar
```

The library where opencv is installed has all the so files and links to so files in place and when I do a ldd on the `libopencv_java310.so` it displays all the associated so files/links are aokay.

However on the machine where opencv is not installed:

I have been able to carry the libs over and create all the links using the ln command however I am still getting

> java.lang.unsatifiedlinkerror: /my/lib/libopencv_java310.so:
>   libopencv_core.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I did an ldd on `libopencv_java310.so` and the result is `libopencv_core.so.3.1` => *not found - one of several not founds in the opencv library.*

The link *`libopencv_core.so.3.1`* is in the directory along with all the other correct link files and their corresponding so files. What am I missing here? I know I need get the `libopencv_java310.so` to find the links but I don't know how.

The end point of this exercise is to make either a self contained executable, .jar or a combination of lib files and .jar to be distributed to end user in the linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the Opencv libraries need to be stored on the installation machine in exactly the same directories as the production machine.  In my case, I may have not used the right directories during my initial installation on the production machine - storing the opencv libraries in my workspace.

First, I created the same directories on the installation PC `/home/me/OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib` and copied all the opencv libraries from the production machine into that directory.

Second, I used ldd `/home/me/opencv_java310.so` to find the libraries with missing links.

Third, I used **ln -s library.file library.link** name to create each link as named in the ldd output.

Fourth, I had to copy over and create links for some libraries stored in the system area `/usr/lib and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` that were also highlighted as missing in the ldd output from opencv_java310.so

Finally, I was able to execute the program java -`Djava.library.path="/home/me/OpenCv/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib" -jar program.jar`

My next step will be to automate this process with either a shell or some other utility and zip files to contain all the data.  I suspect that I should carry ALL the library files from the ldd opencv_java310.so output and create the links just in case the installation machine does not have any of them.